# Why unordered_map::equal_range upper_bound returns end if a key is less than first map element

Tags: c++, stl, unordered-map, equal-range

I've noticed that unordered_map::equal_range upper_bound (first) returns end if the passed key is less than map's first one

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <tr1/unordered_map>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    {
        std::map<char,int> mymap;
        mymap['c'] = 60;
        std::map<char,int>::iterator itup = mymap.equal_range('a').first;
        std::cout << "map::itup " << itup->first << std::endl;
    }

    {
        tr1::unordered_map<char, int> mymap;
        mymap['c'] = 60;
        mymap['d'] = 70;

        tr1::unordered_map<char, int>::iterator itlo = mymap.equal_range('a').first;
        tr1::unordered_map<char, int>::iterator itup = mymap.equal_range('a').second;

        cout << "unordered_map::itup " << (itup == mymap.end() ? "END" : "NOT END") << std::endl;
        cout << "unordered_map::itlo " << (itlo == mymap.end() ? "END" : "NOT END") << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output is:

```
map::itup c
unordered_map::itup END
unordered_map::itlo END
```

Note that the behavior is different for map and unordered_map - any reasons for that or is this a problem in unordered_map?

Comment: because `unordered_map` is, well, **unordered**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happens because an `unordered_map` is, not too surprisingly, unordered.

See §22.2.7 [unord.req], [Table 70](http://eel.is/c++draft/container.requirements#tab:HashRequirements), regarding the requirements on `equal_range`:

> Returns: A range containing all elements with keys equivalent to `k`.
>   Returns `make_­pair(b.end(), b.end())` if no such elements exist.

This is different from the requirements on an ordered associative container, like `std::map`, where `equal_range` is defined in terms of `lower_bound` and `upper_bound`.

`std::unordered_map` doesn't have `lower_bound` and `upper_bound`, for obvious reasons.

Comment: The remaining unclear thing for me here is this spec doesn't mention what should the pair elements contain if k is found. While e.g. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/equal_range does. And http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/unordered_map/unordered_map/equal_range/ looks to be confusing mentioning lower and upper bounds for unordered map.

Answer (score 4):

You asked for a range consisting of all elements in your `unordered_map` whose key is `'a'`. Your unordered map contains no such elements. So, the range is empty.

The same is true of the `map` case. However, the way in which this condition is signified differs by container (although not really; keep reading). The containers `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` are not the same thing (hence they have different names). The former is ordered, whereas the latter is not, so for logical implementation reasons it works slightly differently:

#### `unordered_map`

> [**Return value**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/equal_range)
>   `std::pair` containing a pair of iterators defining the wanted range. If there are no such elements, past-the-end (see `end()`) iterators are returned as both elements of the pair.

#### `map`

> [**Return value**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/equal_range)
>   `std::pair` containing a pair of iterators defining the wanted range: the first pointing to the first element that is not less than `key` and the second pointing to the first element greater than `key`.
>   If there are no elements not less than key, past-the-end (see `end()`) iterator is returned as the first element. Similarly if there are no elements greater than `key`, past-the-end iterator is returned as the second element.)

*This difference does not matter.* In either case you should simply iterate *(`first`, `second`]* to examine the elements (if any exist) in your range, as you would with any iterator range.

In your code, you didn't examine *both* parts of the pair returned in your `map` case. If you do then [you'll find that `first == second`](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a747606ff48a70bd) (again, signifiying an empty range).

**Your `map` code effectively dereferences the "past-the-end" iterator of the returned range.**

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    {
        std::map<char,int> mymap;
        mymap['c'] = 60;
        std::map<char, int>::iterator itlo = mymap.equal_range('a').first;
        std::map<char, int>::iterator itup = mymap.equal_range('a').second;

        // This compares each range extent to the map's end, which is not really useful
        cout << "map::itup " << (itup == mymap.end() ? "END" : "NOT END") << '\n';
        cout << "map::itlo " << (itlo == mymap.end() ? "END" : "NOT END") << '\n';

        // This examines the range itself
        cout << "map range empty: " << (itlo == itup ? "YES" : "NO") << '\n';
        cout << "map range size: " << std::distance(itlo, itup) << '\n';
    }

    {
        std::unordered_map<char, int> mymap;
        mymap['c'] = 60;
        mymap['d'] = 70;

        std::unordered_map<char, int>::iterator itlo = mymap.equal_range('a').first;
        std::unordered_map<char, int>::iterator itup = mymap.equal_range('a').second;

        // This compares each range extent to the map's end, which is not really useful
        cout << "unordered_map::itup " << (itup == mymap.end() ? "END" : "NOT END") << std::endl;
        cout << "unordered_map::itlo " << (itlo == mymap.end() ? "END" : "NOT END") << std::endl;

        // This examines the range itself
        cout << "unordered_map range empty: " << (itlo == itup ? "YES" : "NO") << '\n';
        cout << "unordered_map range size: " << std::distance(itlo, itup) << '\n';
    }
}

// Output:
// 
// map::itup NOT END
// map::itlo NOT END
// map range empty: YES
// map range size: 0
// unordered_map::itup END
// unordered_map::itlo END
// unordered_map range empty: YES
// unordered_map range size: 0
```

#### ([live demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2288ff19e36e0820))